# Why cannot show kinect data on rviz with openni_node.launch?

Tags: kinect, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I run

```
  roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch
  rosrun rviz rviz
```

I set Fixed Frame to /openni_rgb_optical_frame

I change PointCloud2's topic to /camera/rgb/points

Why rviz can't show any point cloud?

[http://imgur.com/7kY5f](https://imgur.com/7kY5f)

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31410/why-cannot-show-kinect-data-on-rviz-with-openni_node.launch?/) by [yichu](https://answers.ros.org/users/2075/yichu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 42 on 2012-04-07

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-04-07**:
Yellow usually indicates that rviz hasn't received any data yet. Could you confirm that your Kinect is publishing data, say by using 'rostopic hz /camera/rgb/points'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Kinect isn't publishing data...

I found that kinect can't work with usb3.0 .
It works with usb2.0 .

---

Originally posted by [yichu](https://answers.ros.org/users/2075/yichu/) with karma: 42 on 2012-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AzureViolin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1837/azureviolin/) on 2012-04-10**:
you're right. to be exact, openni_kinect stack doesn't work with usb3.0.